WIM file and disk addresses
Does a WIM file contain disk addresses of the files it contains?
If I was to create a WIM image of a partition using Dism, and then apply that image to a new partition, again using Dism, would the files be restored to their original disk locations?
And as a related question, would Dism copy \$Mft::$BITMAP?
And as another related question, can the WIM file be applied to a partition that is smaller than the original partition, provided the new partition has enough capacity to accommodate all file data?

“would Dism copy $Mft::$BITMAP?” - No

WIM images are entirely file-based in the same way as ZIP or RAR archives are. Creating and applying a WIM will preserve only externally visible metadata (e.g. NTFS security) but not the internal filesystem layout.
